# In my webserver I found may PHP with random strings

Tags: php, apache

In one of my webserver, I found some new folders got created and many files are there, In access log I found many files access from that folder.

Sample file:

[image]

After this strings:
[image]

But it I copy paste this string to a notepad nothing is visible.

Comment: I cannot see any question. Also, please do not upload screenshots of text; just copy and paste the text.

Comment: This look like an obfuscated wordpress payload. Solution "nuke it from orbit" makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

## Nuke it from orbit!

An attacker compromised your server. It's no longer your server. re-Install the OS, fix the vulnerability in your application and then re-deploy

Comment: It's the only way to be sure.